# How to Force Mathematica to Do a Tick at $x = 1$?

Tags: plotting, labeling, ticks

```
sparseMatrix = 
  SparseArray[{{1, 3} -> s, {1, 4} -> s, {1, 9} -> s*Exp[I m], {2, 
      4} -> -s, {2, 5} -> -s, {3, 
      1} -> -s, {3, 6} -> -s, {4, 1} -> -s, {4, 2} -> -s, {4, 
      7} -> -s, {5, 2} -> -s, {5, 8} -> -s , {6, 3} -> -s, {6, 
      9} -> -s, {7, 4} -> -s, {7, 9} -> -s , {8, 
      5} -> -s, {9, 1} -> -s*Exp[-I m], {9, 
      6} -> -s, {9, 7} -> m^2 ];
```

I have a matrix given whose eigenvalues I want to plot.

Now, I calculate the eigenvalues and want to plot them as a function of $m$, where $m$ is given by $$m = \frac{2\pi n}{N},$$ where $N = 50$ and $n\in\mathbb N$. Thus:

```
eigenvalues = Eigenvalues[Hamiltonian] /. k -> (2 Pi*n/N) /. s -> -1 // FullSimplify;
N = 50.0;
Plot[eigenvalues, {n, 1, N}]
```

To see the output, please run it and you see what I mean.

It's certainly okay, but how canI get Mathematica to show that at the tick $1$, we have $0$, which it currently doesn't..

Comment: You have not provided the definition of the Hamiltonian, which is necessary for people to be able to test your code

Comment: Check `PlotRangePadding` in docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematica apparently doesn't want to put a tick label too close to the vertical axis.  You could fix this by using the `AxesOrigin` command:

```
Plot[eigenvalues, {n, 1, N1}, Ticks -> {{{1, -Pi}, {100, 0}, {200, Pi}}, Automatic}, AxesOrigin -> {100, 0}]
```

[image]

Of course, now you don't have the `Tick` at zero, which may also be suboptimal. (I would argue that this is an improvement, though, since it is easier to see that the center of this plot is 0 than it is to see that the left bound of your original plot is -π.)

Alternately, use a `Frame` and `FrameTicks` instead of `Axes`:

```
 Plot[eigenvalues, {n, 1, N1}, FrameTicks -> {{{1, -Pi}, {100, 0}, {200, Pi}}, Automatic}, 
   Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> {0, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Comment: @Hermi: My pleasure. If you found this answer (or any other answer) particularly useful in answering your question, please "accept" it by clicking the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you, please, have a look at the output of the following command? Is this what you were looking for or did I misunderstand?

```
eigenvalues = 
  Eigenvalues[Hamiltonian] /. k -> (-Pi + 2 Pi*n/N1) /. t -> 2.97 // 
   FullSimplify;
N1 = 200.0;
(*Plot as a function of k*)
Plot[eigenvalues, {n, 1, N1}, 
 Ticks -> {{1, Pi}, Range[-2 Pi, 2 Pi, Pi]}]
```

You can observe the small part `Range[-2 Pi, 2 Pi, Pi]` inside the `Ticks` and hopefully you can play around as well

Comment: Don't mention it. I am glad I was able to help :-)